# Squash commit message in master branch

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit, git-squash

In Git after last push to remote repo I worked on master branch. I have 6 commits to push now. I want to squash these 6 into 1 commit message then do push.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with writing a new commit message

```
git reset --soft HEAD~6
git commit
```

This will the last 6 commits and put them back in the staging area.
The subsequent commit will then include all the changes.

If you instead want to preserve the commit messages

```
git rebase -i HEAD~6
```

and in the interactive editor, replace 'pick' with 'fixup' for the last 5 commits.

This will create a unique commit, containing all the 6 commit messages.